# Select all the rows up to the first 0 in a group

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to build a list of clients and what their AR history was seance the last time it was 0. here is a example

I want to turn this

```
ID       ClientID   Total   Balance
67202   122         63.01   63.01
66234   122         60.94   60.94
65738   122         278.47  0
62144   122         69.61   69.61
61662   122         13.65   13.65
61625   122         169.79  0
67618   49          47.37   47.37
62112   49          44.02   0
```

into this

```
ID     ClientID    Total   Balance
67202   122         63.01   63.01
66234   122         60.94   60.94
67618   49          47.37   47.37
```

Notice that the record 62144 and 61662 where not included because there was a 0 between them and the top two records.

Removing records like 62144 and 61662 is my hangup. If i just wanted to remove the 0's I could just do a `Balance <> 0` but I only want the top records up to the first 0.

Here is the query I have so far to get me where I am now

```
select * from [Artrxs]
where [clientid] in (
    SELECT [ClientID]
    FROM [Artrxs]
    where [id] in (
        select max([id])  --Find the newest record for each client
        FROM [Artrxs] 
        group by clientid)
    and [balance] <> 0) --only show clients who's newest record is not 0
order by [clientid], [id] desc
```

Worst case, I am iterating over the list anyway in code for the report I can just start skipping till I hit a new client ID. But I would really like to be able to do this all in one SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define what the "first" means for the first 0 in your query.  In this case, as there's no datetime column I'm assuming the IDs are sequential by time, as well.  That gives me this query:

```
WITH LastZeroByClient AS (
    SELECT ClientID, MAX(ID) AS ZeroID FROM Artrxs WHERE Balance = 0 GROUP BY ClientID
)
SELECT columns
FROM Artrxs t
INNER JOIN LastZeroByClient z ON h.ClientID=z.ClientID AND h.ID > z.ZeroID
```

Note that I originally had a LEFT JOIN, but then I noticed a snippet later in your question that said you want to exclude clients who's last ID is already zero.

Also, you could still do this with a derived table (sub query).  I personally find derived tables more readable, but CTE's easier to write.

Comment: I removed the datetime column to simplify the table i was posting but yes, the Id column is identity column that just increments with each newly added record (so records with newer dates will have higher ids)

Comment: Need a `where Balance = 0` in the CTE, I think?

Comment: And first is defined as the record with the highest id